# Test Laravel Flash Session

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

how can I test in Laravel a Flash Session?
In my test case I have two routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return redirect("/")->with('mysession', 1);
});
```

And my test is:

```
public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->followingRedirects()->get('/login');
        $response->assertSessionHas('mysession');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

This test fails with the error: `Session is missing expected key [mysession].`

Has any one an idea how I can test this simple setup?

I'am using a fresh installed Laravel 5.8

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're kinda checking the session/response of the `/` request not the `/login` it self. Adding `followingRedirects()` before `get('/login')` method, will "skip" the response of that request to the redirected one, so you're basically checking if:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Has flashed a session key or not. Which is not according to your code up there.

Now to make your test pass, you should remove `followingRedirects()` from the chain. Also note that your second assertion will fail because a redirect status is `302` not `200`